# How should images be stored when multiple sizes are needed?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, image-manipulation

What is the best way to store images? Currently when an image is uploaded I resize it to 3 different sizes (a thumbnail, a normal size, and a large size). I save in a database a description of the image, the format, and use the id number from the database as the image name. Each size image has its own directory.

Should I be storing the images in the database? Should I only be storing the larger size and generate the thumbnail as needed? Or any other ideas you have?

Comment: What's your application? Social network? Stock photos?

Comment: Sales of RVs. The dealer is loading about 20 - 30 images per RV and usually has about 100 - 200 RVs. I also have plans for a larger scale app that will possibly have 10,000+ items with several images for each item.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517752/images-in-database-vs-file-system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you described sounds reasonable to me. You could store the images in your database but you wouldn't notice any major performance boosts and, if your webhost limits the size of your MySQL database, you might find you're overpaying for database space.

As for resizing the images, doing it once and storing the three copies is way less computationally expensive than generating smaller images once per request; however, you may want to consider having the browser do your thumbnail generation for you (just specify an img tag with the src set to the full size image plus width/height attributes), which would allow you to save CPU power and disk space at the expensive of having not-so-pretty thumbnails (browsers generally scale images for speed at the expensive of quality).

Answer (score 2):

You can choose a mix of both worlds, saving the big image on the SQL (or HDD). 
You generate the thumbnails on the fly when requested, but then cache them on the server for a certain ammount of time.

This means at any time you will have on the disk the big images and the thumbnails for the most recent / frequently used ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a drupal powered site, this functionality is built in with http://drupal.org/project/imagecache

Comment: Im am not using a CMS. I have plans to build an app from scratch that I do not want to use a CMS for.