# User pictures in php

Tags: php, mysql, photos

I'm making a user plateform on my website with php/mysql, and I want to know if is it good to allow users add photos using the mysql blob file, or adding their photos in a folder with their id, and storing every photo's path with a VARCHAR variable into the database.
Thanks

Comment: second option is better than saving file data in blob

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182315/store-image-files-or-urls-in-mysql-database-which-is-better or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517752/images-in-database-vs-file-system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always do the following:

1. rename the image
2. store it in a folder of your choosing
3. store the location of the image in a varchar column in your mysql
   table.

simple and effective.